# How to open software keyboard on Windows Mobile device?

Tags: windows-mobile

Some of Windows Mobile applications like [pocketwit](http://code.google.com/p/pocketwit/) hide the button for showing/hiding software keyboard. It sometimes shows up when I click into the textbox, but that doesn't work here either.

It is like fourth application where I have this problem. I have HTC Touch Diamond, so I don't have hardware keyboard. I also didn't find any mapping for opening keyboard.

Is it possible to somehow override application settings to show the *keyboard button* or any other way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is go to Settings -> Buttons and assign a key to "< Input Panel >" and on  my WinMo phone this brings up the keyboard or input panel that is currently active.  Annoyingly you have to hold the button to keep the keyboard open but it could be useful if you can't see the button to get rid of the keyboard either.

The "< Input Panel >" command will be near the top of the item list.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit as < and > got the helpful text cropped.

Comment: Duplicated on my HTC Hero/ATT Tilt - but I didn't have to hold the button down to keep the keyboard... I also didn't try it using the pocketwit software. I refuse to use twitter. ;)